# I have a pseudocode problem, I don't know where to put my code

Tags: java

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            init();

            solve();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

ok so I got this for a default pseudocode format but I don't know where to put my code!

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not that clear what you are asking. What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: Where have you tried putting it?

Comment: Since we don't know what the code is supposed to do, we don't either. What are `init`, `solve`, `in` and `close`?

Comment: This is the problem: http://usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=891

Comment: and this is the solution: http://usaco.org/current/data/sol_shell_bronze_jan19.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code tries to execute the functions init() and solve(). If there is an exception, it will print it out with

```
 catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

You can replace the init() and solve() with the code you want to be executed, and choose what you want to do with the error in the catch block.